# What should I use to compile C++ on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, unix

I'm a C++ programmer that is coming from a UNIX environment compiling in GCC that wants to start to compile programs for Windows. What would you guys recommend in terms of IDE/Compiler? What really am I going to be looking at what's different versus these two environments? I don't plan to do anything really fancy with my applications, just would like a basic terminal window with input and output so I can write a few basic applications.

I've already begun to download Visual Studio 2012 express but I'd like to get some more opinions.

Thanks.

Comment: VS Express will do the job fine.

Comment: if you are used for unix-like environment - try mingw/msys - it's all the usual gnu toolchain + core utilities.

Comment: @aleguna Including `gdb`?  I use Visual Studios 2012 for development under Windows, and the debugger is one of the worst I've ever encountered.  (Until a couple of months ago, I had access to a Linux machine as well, and anytime the going got rough, I could switch to it: g++ has better error messages, and gdb, while not the most comfortable, is still an order of magnitude better than the Visual Studios debugger.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: re your view of the Visual Studio debugger, I think you're in a minority of 1. just don't expect core dumps. use it the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: @JamesKanze, yes gdb is included as well

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  you can always generate crash dumps. You could also hook up your app with WinDbg if you are a command-line debugger extraordinaire. But I agree with your sentiment - James Kanze's views seem strange esp. when he is not backing things up with any explanation or evidence.

Comment: @Alf I don't expect core dumps when I'm running under the debugger.  But the Visual Studios debugger generally displays 4 or 5 windows with information you don't want, but makes it difficult, if not impossible, to display information you do want.  (It is a nice browser for code you don't understand.  But it's lousy if you really do understand the code, but it's just not working the way you think it should.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Learn to use WinDbg. You will be surprised...

Answer (score 7):

`VS Express for Desktop` is far better than any IDE I've ever used on Linux.

Comment: It's can only be used for non-commercial projects

Comment: @aleguna That was true for VS2010 but doesn't seem to be the case for VS2012

Answer (score 2):

In Windows you should primarily use Microsoft's compiler [**Visual c++**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B), supplemented with

- alternatives for optimization (e.g. the [Intel C++ compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B)),
- front ends for standards compliance (I don't know any current, but for C++03 you could use [Comeau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeau_C/C%2B%2B)), and
- a “number 2” compiler just to check for portability, which is simply the GNU toolchain's [**g++** compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%2B%2B) (alternatively one can compile truly portable source code in *nix, but that does not help for Windows-specific code: g++ does support Windows-specific things).

Visual C++ and g++ are free.

For professional work the company should purchase the full **Visual Studio** IDE and an **MSDN library** subscription. As a student you get the full Visual Studio for free, through the [Dreamspark program](https://www.dreamspark.com/). As a hobbyist one gets [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop) for free (and myself, as a hobbyist, got the full Visual Studio as a gift from Microsoft, dunno why they like me so).

Intel and Comeau are, as far as I know, commercial only.

Comment: VS 2012 supports a lot of C++11

Comment: @James: not really, as far as the core language is concerned. but it does have `auto` and range based `for`, and implements the regexp library as well as threading, which g++ lacks as of version 4.7.2. the november 2012 CTP has experimental support for some more features, including variadic templates. as i recall scott meyers has a comparison chart for various compilers, with their c++11 support (and lack thereof). you might google it up. ;-)

Comment: @Alf It also has lambda's: `lambda` and `auto` don't really allow you to do anything you couldn't do otherwise, but they do mean a lot less typing, and shorter, more readable lines.  (For the rest of C++, I've been disappointed.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: No offense but when it comes to Visual C++ or Microsoft, something or the other is going to disappoint you no matter what. No surprise there I guess...

Comment: @Dilip When it comes to VC++ or Microsoft, yes, there's always something to disappoint me.  Not calling destructors, in pre VC++10.  Error messages that don't show enough information.  An OS which masks directories, so that different programs see different contents for the same path.  (The old Sequent machines experimented with that under Unix---25 years ago.  It was a bad idea then, and it's been driving us up the wall now.)  For whatever reasons, Microsoft always seems to be about 20 years behind everyone else.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "20 years behind". consider that Windows Vista got symlinks already in 2007. now you can't seriously maintain that that's long after unix got them, can you? ;-p okay, i had to make my own symlink command since microsoft's, `mklink`, only works in an elevated command prompt, like running under root in *nix. that's sort of pretty unwholesome design, yes. and it involved spinning off a separate COM server executable just in order to get access to the elevation API programmatically. yes, a tad complicated. but! eh...

Comment: @JamesKanze: "masks directories" -- i gather you worked out that, but do be critically aware that the same is true of the registry tools, including regedit. in windows 7 the ordinary regedit is a 64-bit executable, and it looks exactly like the 32-bit one but gives a slightly different view of the registry. :-(

Comment: @Alf Hard links were present in the earliest Unix, and symbolic links were introduced in the first Berkley kernel---over 25 years ago.  And I've had multiple desktops under Unix since at least 20 years ago---you still don't have them under Windows.  Windows is catching up (I can remember when it was still MS-DOS---and Unix was in advance of modern Windows).  But it's got a long way to go.  (The real progress, IMHO, is that they seem to want to get there.  That wasn't always the case.)

Comment: @Alf With regards to masking directories... it took me two days to realize what was going on, and I only realized it then because I was analysing the problem with CygWin tools like file (and comparing the size of the DLLs using both `dir` and `ls`, and getting different values---CygWin is still pure 32 bits).

Comment: he he. well closed questions are nice for discussions. well as you probably understood that thing about ms not lagging was very much tongue in cheek. however, it so happens that while apparently the GUI guys at microsoft do all sorts of harebrained ungood things, the architecture guys, hidden in the basement perhaps, do Very Good Things. they're just not exposed to the user. thus, Windows does have multiple desktop support, but it's just not exposed. there are lots of utilities for it, including [one from ms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx). likewise much else!

Answer (score -1):

Use TurboC++ or just TurboC. IT is available for free online. But Visual Studio or to be specific Visual C++ is anytime better considering UI.

Comment: -1 Turbo C++ is from the middle 1990's, before the first C++ standard.

Comment: @Alf And I don't think it has been updated in a long, long time.  (G++ is even older than Turbo C++, but there've been some significant improvements since then.)